# jquery `$form.find` get element inside form

Tags: jquery, html

I have this JQuery code:

```
if ($form.find('.required').filter(function(){ return this.value === '' }).length > 0) {

}
```

within this if statement, how can i get each element and add a class to it?

i tried `$(this).addClass("EmptySelect");` but it just adds the class to the form itself and not the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform `addClass` right after the `filter()` call

```
    var emptyElements = $form.find('.required').filter(function() {
        return this.value === ''
    });
    if (emptyElements.length > 0) {
        emptyElements.addClass("EmptySelect");
    }
```

However, you can just connect the `filter` statement with `addClass` without the `if` since filter will only return the empty elements

```
$form.find('.required').filter(function() {
            return this.value === ''
        }).addClass("EmptySelect");
```

Comment: where do i add this in my code? it looks like some of my code has been removed?

Comment: @charlie, see my updated answer. But if you think about it, you can just connect the `filter` statement with `addClass` without the `if` since filter will only return the empty elements

Comment: i just tried `alert(emptyElements);` but its showing `[object Object]` and not the element name / id

Comment: @charlie, right, `filter` will return a jQuery collection object. Is the answer still not working?

Comment: well its not adding the class

Comment: @charlie, it is adding the class, but you dont have any styles for that class. See http://jsfiddle.net/zy8mz05L/1/

Comment: perfect! thank you. would there be an easy way to add a tool tip to this as well?

Comment: where should that be displaying?

Comment: @charlie, I think that qualifies for a new question :)